# How to sort the values (from smallest to larger) of a column in an ascii file using python?

Tags: python, sorting, ascii

I have an ASCII file with the following columns :

```
ID, val1, val2, val3
```

where ID is a row_number but not sorted. I want to write a new ascii file with the same columns with sorted ID (from smaller to larger).

How I could do that in python?

In fact, this file has been produced by the concatenation of 2 ascii files using the following code:

```
  import os.path


    maindir1="/home/d01/"

maindir2="/home/d02/"
outdir="/home/final/"

    pols=[ "F1","F2","F3" ]

    months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

    for ipol in pols:
        for imonth in months:
            for kk in range(1, 7):
                template_args = {"ipol": ipol, "imonth": imonth, "kk": kk}
                filename = "{ipol}_{imonth}_0{kk}_L1.txt".format(ipol=ipol, imonth=imonth, kk=kk)
                out_name = os.path.join(outdir, filename)
                in_names = [os.path.join(maindir1, filename), os.path.join(maindir2, filename)]
                with open(out_name, "w") as out_file:
                    for in_name in in_names:
                        with open(in_name, "r") as in_file:
                            out_file.write(in_file.read())
```

How could I define to the above code to write the final file in a sorted way (based on the first column) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assuming Comma Separated Values

I think you're talking about a Comma Separated Values (CSV) file. The character encoding is probably ASCII. If this is true, you'll have an input like this:

```
id,val1,val2,val3
3,a,b,c
1,a,b,c
2,a,b,c
```

Python has a good standard library for this: `csv`.

```py
import csv

with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

We import the `csv` library first, then open the file using a context processor. Basically, it's a nice way to open the file, do stuff (in the `with` block) and then close it.

The `csv.reader` method takes the file pointer `f` as an argument. This reader can be iterated and represents the contents of your file. If you cast it to a list, you get a list of lists. The first item in the list of lists is the header, which you want to save, and the rest is the contents:

```py
contents = list(reader)
header = contents[0]
rows = contents[1:]
```

You then want to sort the rows. But sorting a list of lists might not do what you expect. You need to write a function that helps you find the key to use to perform the sorting:

```py
lambda line: line[0]
```

This means for every `line` (which we expect to be a list), the key is equal to the first member of the list. If you prefer not to use lambdas, you can also define a function:

```py
def get_key(line):
    return line[0]
```

`get_key` is identical to the lambda.

Combine this all together to get:

```py
new_file = sorted(rows, key=lambda line: line[0])
```

If you didn't use the lambda, that's:

```py
new_file = sorted(rows, key=get_key)
```

To write it to a file, you can use the `csv` library again. Remember to first write the header then the rest of the contents:

```py
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(new_file)
```

All together, the code looks like this:

```py
import csv

with open("in.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    contents = list(reader)
    header = contents[0]
    rows = contents[1:]

    new_file = sorted(rows, key=lambda line: line[0])

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(new_file)
```

### Assuming Custom

If the file is custom and definitely has the spaces in the header like you described (*almost* like a CSV) or you don't want to use the `csv` library, you can extract rows like this:

```py
contents = [row.replace(" ", "").split(",") for row in f.readlines()]
```

If, for instance, it's space-delimited instead of comma-delimited, you would use this:

```py
contents = [row.split() for row in f.readlines()]
```

You can write rows like this:

```py
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(", ".join(header))

    for row in new_file:
        f.write(", ".join(row))
```

In ensemble:

```py
with open("in.txt") as f:
    contents = [row.replace(" ", "").split(",") for row in f.readlines()]
    header = contents[0]
    rows = contents[1:]

    new_file = sorted(rows, key=lambda line: line[0])

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(", ".join(header))

    for row in new_file:
        f.write(", ".join(row))
```

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** This would perform a lexicographical sort on the first column, which is probably not what you want. If you can guarantee that all of the first column (aside from the header) are integers, you can just cast them from a `str`:

```py
lambda line: line[0]
```

...becomes:

```py
lambda line: int(line[0])
```

...with full code:

```py
import csv

with open("in.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    contents = list(reader)
    header = contents[0]
    rows = contents[1:]

    new_file = sorted(rows, key=lambda line: int(line[0]))

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(new_file)
```

Comment: thank you very much, I tried the first solution but in the output file the rows were not sorted from the smallest (i.e..1 ) to the largest (i.e. 100000) but rows in the output had the following order: 1, 10, 100, 1000 etc . How I could sort the data from the smallest value to the largest?

Comment: The first row are strings rather than integers which are sorted lexicographically. If you are sure that they are always going to be integers, you may cast them. I will edit my answer to include this detail.

Comment: thank you. the first column is always integer but the next one are floats. I got an error:  new_file = sorted(rows, key=lambda line: int(line[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '116551  .2524719834  .2524719834  .2524719834'

Comment: I didn't refer that the input file is an ASCII file with space separated columns.I tried the second solution as:         
contents = [row.replace(" ", " ").split(" ") for row in f.readlines()], it reads the file correct   but it does not sort the data at all. Do I have to call the new_file in the output? (as in the first case?)

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that this was _comma_-separated, not space-separated. So you were right in trying the "Assuming Custom" section. Apologies, I didn't explain why I used the `replace()` method to begin with. I will edit my answer.

Comment: But the general idea of the `str.replace(a, b)` method in Python is to replace every sequence `a` with another sequence `b`. Right now, you are trying to replace a space with another space, effectively doing nothing. Not a big deal, as it shouldn't cause your program to fail. When you split it (by the way, `split()` is the same as `split(" ")`) you create a list of values delimited by a space, which is what you want. Aside from the extra commas in the header, this seems correct.

Comment: Finally, the reason I used `replace` in the first place was to remove unnecessary space characters. You can safely remove that call.

Comment: thank you. But why it doesn't sort the data finally? is the last row of the code in the second solution correct? it seems that it doesn't use the new_file?

Comment: Could I see your input data? Just the header and a few rows is enough.

Comment: Ohhhh... whoops. Long day. Yup, I'll edit my post. Teaches me to post an answer without testing it first.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to sort the data in csv format you have in ascending order on the basis of Id.
You can use this function to do it

```
def Sort(sub_li): 
    sub_li.sort(key = lambda x: x[0]) 
    return sub_li
```

x[0] to sort according to Id means first column or you can change according to your use case.
I took the input as `

```
a = [["1a", 122323,1000,0],
    ["6a", 12323213,24,2],
     ["3a", 1233,1,3]]
```

So, using the above function I got the output as

```
[['1a', 122323, 1000, 0], 
 ['3a', 1233, 1, 3], 
 ['6a', 12323213, 24, 2]]
```

I hope this will help.